# supabase OAuth with predefined Login Component

Tags: reactjs, oauth, supabase

I want to login with github using the custom Auth component from supabase. the docs from supabase say that i should call the `signInWithGithub` function when the user submits the form but where can i use the `signInWithGitHub` function after submitting the form?

```
const Login = () => {
    async function signInWithGitHub() {
        const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
            provider: 'github',
        })
        console.log(data, error)
    }

    return (
        <div className='h-screen max-w-md mx-auto grid items-center'>
            <Auth
                supabaseClient={supabase}
                appearance={{
                    theme: ThemeSupa,
                }}
                theme="dark"
                providers={
                    ['google', 'github']
                }
                socialLayout="horizontal"
            />
        </div>
    )
};

export default Login;
```

Comment: Can you add links to the things you mention? Like this supabase thing and the docs where it says to use that function.

Comment: Yes, ofc: 
https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/auth-github . If you scroll down you will see the docs say to use the function. But this is with using a custom theme not with the predefined supabase auth component

Comment: That's what I was trying to understand, to be able to answer you :) Glad you fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind it works now ... you don't need that signInWithGithub function when using the predefined auth component :D

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).